# How to count with while loop and prevent undefined offset without knowing how much elements to count?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, counting

When counting with a while loop (within a 'for loop') I use not a length-parameter but this function:

```
function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return $needle === "" || substr($haystack, -strlen($needle)) === $needle;
}
```

With the help of that I loop through an array of preview thumbnails and pdf-sourcefiles. But i just wanna count the files ending with jpg. So my code for the while loop is:

```
while(endWith($page_counter[$rrr], '.jpg')){ 
                $rrr++;
                $document_page_count++;                                       
                $page_counter['pdf'][$pdf_counting-1]=$document_page_count;
            }
```

With that I always get the Notice: "Undefined offset: 10". I already tried some stuff with "isset" and comparing $rrr with all counting parameters I have but it didnt help. Is it possible to prevent the undefined offset somehow? Sorry, but i can't post the whole code.

Any ideas?

Comment: `isset()` should do the job so your code is probably incorrect. But since we can't see it, we can't help you.

Comment: while(endWith($page_counter[$rrr], '.jpg') && isset($page_counter[$rrr+1])){                   
                    $rrr++;
                    $document_page_count++;    I tried that and there is no warning anymore. Maybe that's the answer
                    $page_counter['pdf'][$pdf_counting-1]=$document_page_count+1;
                    //var_dump($document_page_count);                   
                    
                }

Answer (score 0):

```
while (isset($page_counter[$rrr]) && endWith($page_counter[$rrr], '.jpg')) ...
```

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it didnt work. But with: while(endWith($page_counter[$rrr], '.jpg') && isset($page_counter[$rrr+1])){ $rrr++; $document_page_count++; I tried that and there is no warning anymore. Maybe that's the answer $page_counter['pdf'][$pdf_counting-1]=$document_page_count+1; it seems to work now